# I am getting error when trying to proxying using request library in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I am getting error when trying to run the following code. I want to connect to some url (facebook.com in example).I am getting error.

```
    var request = require('request');
    request.get({
     url: "https://www.facebook.com",
     proxy: '35.199.76.79:80',
     tunnel:true
  }
     ,function(err,res,body){
    if(err) console.log(err)
    else console.log(res)
});
```

Error Stack:

```
{ Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect EINVAL 0.0.0.80:80 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)
    at ClientRequest.onError (/home/ujwal/Documents/Projects/proxy-tester/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:177:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9) code: 
    'ECONNRESET' }
```

Comment: please post the stack trace

Comment: `proxy: proxyIP+proxyPort` - it's `35.199.76.7980`, isn't it?

Comment: @estus thanks, i edited the question. :)

Comment: Did you test the proxy to be workable? Can you open `https://www.facebook.com` in a browser with this proxy? Does the request work without `proxy` option?

Comment: Yes, the request work without proxy options. How do i open https://www.facebook.com in browser with proxy options?

Comment: Configure a browser to use a proxy. If you're not sure how to do this for your browser, google that. You need to use `@` on SO in order for users to receive notifications.

Comment: What I want to achieve finally is to develop a webapp where user may enter random proxy and random website and I want to test speed of that website through the proxy entered by user. So, I wont know what proxy address the user enters, and I think its not possible to configure all the proxies.

Answer (score 0):

if you are behind a proxy, I think you should first setup the npm proxy settings

```
    npm config set proxy 35.199.76.79:80
    npm config set https-proxy 35.199.76.79:80
```

Comment: What I want to achieve finally is that user may enter random proxy and random website and I want to test speed of that website through the proxy entered by user. So, I wont know what proxy address the user enters, and I think its not possible to configure all the proxies.